# How to define configuration parameters in Java?

Tags: java

My main function uses set of hard coded parameters as given in the sample code. 
Objective: I want a cleaner code instead of hard coding these values inside main. 
Question: WIs there a way of defining all these parameters in a separate file like a configuration file and enabling access to main? Anybody who wants to change values will be required to modify only the parameter file. If there is a better way of handling the objective, please suggest so.

```
    public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
            // parameter list
            String Parameter_1 = "Value_1";
            String Parameter_2 = "Value_2";
            .......
            //Function code
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at Java properties files; you can easily load (and save) them using the class `java.util.Properties`.

A properties file is a text file that contains key-value pairs, for example like this:

```
Parameter_1=Value_1
Parameter_2=Value_2
```

Loading a properties file is very easy:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
props.load(in);
in.close();
```

Then you can get the values:

```
String Parameter_1 = props.get("Parameter_1");
```

Comment: +1, OP is trying to get rid of hardcoded values, so you could notice that the properties filename needn't be hardcoded either, he can use `args[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
               //load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

               //get the property value and print it out
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Value_1"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Value_2"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("Value_3"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html) is the preferred way, over Properties, at least as of Java 1.4. There's actually a [comparison](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html#prefs-other) between other approaches and Preferences.